# Additonal layer of abstraction for GNU screen region management?

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

Here is my use case: I have maybe 10 or so windows open in screen. I want to be able to split my terminal into regions and assign windows to regions. So far, so good. However, I want to be able to easily switch between different region configurations within a single screen session, which AFAIK cannot be done. For example, say I have my todo list, IRC, vim editing some code, and ssh to server 1 and server 2. I want "vim editing some code" to take the full terminal region, but I want to have another configuration of regions that are split for the other four. Is this possible? I would be ok with using tmux or something else, as long as it can do what I want.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tmux can do this with "windows". A window is an arrangement of "panes" that you can easily switch between. A "pane" in tmux is a region where your process is running, ie vim, etc.